# Error "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found" on mobile - Tomcat

Tags: javascript, html, css, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I hope you're all fine!

I just finished working on my first web application using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. As soon as I finished it, I hosted it in an AWS server, plus used Apache Tomcat.

Every time I try to access the website through a pc computer and tablets, it works perfectly. On the other hand, when I try to access it through a phone it doesn't work, it just pops up an error page (I'll attach the image down below)

[image: The error message]

Comment: Looks like you have some javascript that redirects some devices to a page called mobile.html. Is your homepage index.html? What is your expected behaviour with a mobile?

Comment: I am trying to Detect the mobile device and redirecting the responsive page. Using this code: <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "index.htm";
    }
    //-->
  </script>
  <script language="javascript">
    <!--
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    location.replace("index.htm");
    }
    -->
  </script>            but now I no longer see the error because it replaces the mobile.html page with index.htm but it doesn't load well on mobile devices

Comment: You should edit your question title and make it about javsacript page redirects. Then edit your question and include your redirect code, as well as your website file structure. Use the markup features to ensure your code is well formatted.